# ConcurrentHashMap JDK 8 to JDK 6 backport

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, backport

ConcurrentHashMap in Java 8 does not use locks, although 6 and 7 JDK implementation do. Is there a backport of the Java 8 implementation to Java 6 ?

Reason : no locks => no contention => better performance.

Comment: Are the locks a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Yes, if mostly 2 to 3 buckets used. Plus, there are multiple writers (with almost real-time updates)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the times measured for Java 8 and earlier respectively?

Comment: Could you specify exactly what metrics you have used to confirm that the lock-free Java-8 solution is the only one appropriate to your problem? Please see [Parallel Parking](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue217.html) and [Parallel Parking b](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue217b.html) for a pertinent discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Since Apr 2014 we had already migrated our product to Java8, so it is not a pressing issue anymore for us. For those who still have this problem look at Doug Lea's [jsr166e](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/). [Docs](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166edocs/), [the jar compiled under Java6](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166.jar).

As a side note: now even twitter has put a part of those classes into a jar [twitter/jsr166e](https://github.com/twitter/jsr166e) compiled under Java6 :).

Comment: The twitter link is a subset of classes but links to full source of jsr166e [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/), links in answer are broken.

Answer (score 1):

There are backports for at least Java 7, see this one from [Infinispan](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/util/concurrent/jdk8backported/ConcurrentHashMapV8.html), this is their [blog post](http://blog.infinispan.org/2012/03/jdk-8-backported-concurrenthashmaps-in.html) about it. It should also work in Java 6, it's probably worth to download the infinispan jar and test it out.

Comment: close : "Hi,
unfortunately this does not work with JDK6, because the ConcurrentMapFactory checks for existance of com.sun.unsafe.Unsafe instead of sun.misc.Unsafe. I opened a JIRA issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-2237
Robert"

Comment: Is the whole library a one-jar ? Or, to put it simpler, could I get the meat = concurrency backport?

Comment: I don't know if it's only that the problem, but it seems its worth giving it a go by copying the source to the project and redoing the import with the different package name. It could be just that

Comment: The source can be found here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.infinispan/infinispan-core/5.1.5.FINAL/org/infinispan/util/concurrent/jdk8backported/ConcurrentHashMapV8.java

Answer (score 0):

Netty has [backport](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/chmv8/ConcurrentHashMapV8.java) and Netty's language level is Java 6.

Comment: Please look at my answer.